# FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter onDataChanged is called but getItemCount() always return 0

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm using [`FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter.java) which gets a keyRef and dataRef and is very helpful with getting all dataRef's children which their keys exists as children in keyRef.

The data is being displayed correctly but if i'm overriding `onDataChanged` for hiding a progress bar and/or displaying an empty state depends on the itemsCount (Something which i've already done with `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and works as expected) but `getItemCount` always return 0(!)

```
private class MYAdapter extends FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Item, ItemHolder> {
    .
    .

    @Override
    protected void onDataChanged() {
        super.onDataChanged();
        // getItemCount() == 0 here always
    }

    .
    .
}
```

I've investigate it and the reason is that `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` is using `FirebaseIndexArray` which is overriding `getItemCount` and return `mDataSnapshots.size()` but the data was not loaded yet - the `onDataChanged` was called because the keyRef loaded - and indeed i can see in debug that the keys are loaded (with the correct count) but unfortunately they are private so i can't use them to get the count.

I know i can override `onChildChanged` and then call `getItemCount` and get the correct count (which i've done) but still i can't know if there are no items and i need to display the empty state.

Using `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0`

Is there something i'm missing?

**Note** - I know i can manage my own count (child) beside the data and just load it before setting the adapter but i'm saving this as a last resort.

Thanks!

Comment: Reading words is easier for most of us than reading code. Please post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  But if you think you've found a bug, you're better off reporting an [issue on the FirebaseUI-Android github repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after opening a [issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/719) in the FirebaseUI-Android github repo, as suggested by @Frank van Puffelen, i got an answer from @SUPERCILEX saying that `onDataChanged` is indeed broken in `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` and will be fixed in v2.0 which will be coming soon.